# Get exact employee count on LinkedIn?

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I'm looking to pull the exact employee count for a given company on LinkedIn. From what I have found, this data is not accessible through the API or on the public site, so the only remaining option I see is to programmatically authenticate and scrape the company page for logged-in users. Anyone have other ideas or know how to do that?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you are dead set on getting an exact number by scraping the site, by far the easiest way to do that is with [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) in Python. In short, you give it a webaddress, and it gives all the data back to you in the form of an easily traverse-able object.

For the employee count, depending on where a person's company information is displayed, it could be as simple as giving it all the people you wish to check on, then doing

```
All_Companies[body.companyDiv.companyName]++
```

I really hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The best that you are going to get from LinkedIn is via the `<employee-count-range>` element of the [Company API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/company-lookup-api-and-fields). The legend for its values is as follows:

```
A = 1
B = 2-10
C = 11-50
D = 51-200
E = 201-500
F = 501-1000
G = 1001-5000
H = 5001-10000
I = 10001+
```

Comment: This is unfortunately not accurate enough, but thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
LinkedInApiClientFactory mfactory = LinkedInApiClientFactory.newInstance(Constants.consumerKey, Constants.consumerSecret);
        CompaniesApiClient clientcompany = mfactory.createCompaniesApiClient(Constants.token, Constants.tokenSecret);
        Company company = clientcompany.getCompanyById("YOUR PAGE ID", EnumSet.allOf(CompanyField.class));
if (company.getEmployeeCountRange().getCode().equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
       System.out.println("-->Emplyee count--"+"1");
    }else if (company.getEmployeeCountRange().getCode().equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
         System.out.println("-->Emplyee count--"+"2-10");
    }
    else if (company.getEmployeeCountRange().getCode().equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
         System.out.println("-->Emplyee count--"+"11-50");
    }
    else if (company.getEmployeeCountRange().getCode().equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
         System.out.println("-->Emplyee count--"+"51-200");
    }
    else if (company.getEmployeeCountRange().getCode().equalsIgnoreCase("E")) {
         System.out.println("-->Emplyee count--"+"201-500");
    }
    else if (company.getEmployeeCountRange().getCode().equalsIgnoreCase("F")) {
         System.out.println("-->Emplyee count--"+"501-1000");
    }
    else if (company.getEmployeeCountRange().getCode().equalsIgnoreCase("G")) {
         System.out.println("-->Emplyee count--"+"1001-5000");
    }
    else if (company.getEmployeeCountRange().getCode().equalsIgnoreCase("H")) {
         System.out.println("-->Emplyee count--"+"50001-10000");
    }
    else if (company.getEmployeeCountRange().getCode().equalsIgnoreCase("H")) {
     System.out.println("-->Emplyee count--"+"10000 and above");
   }
```